# Ansible failed to connect to Windows node via SSH

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, ansible, openssh

I am trying to configure a Windows node running OpenSSH (https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) via Ansible. While normal SSH connection works, Ansible seems to fail to connect to the node.

Normal SSH connection:

```
sysadmin@MY_LINUX_SERVER:~/ansible$ ssh administrator@MY_WINDOWS_HOST -vvvv
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to MY_WINDOWS_HOST [A.B.C.D] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "MY_WINDOWS_HOST" from file "/home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 1b:1b:43:b9:74:34:48:0b:06:9d:11:9c:9b:51:56:61
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "MY_WINDOWS_HOST" from file "/home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "A.B.C.D" from file "/home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host 'MY_WINDOWS_HOST' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/sysadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/sysadmin/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
administrator@MY_WINDOWS_HOST's password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 64 padlen 16 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to MY_WINDOWS_HOST ([A.B.C.D]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

administrator@MY_WINDOWS_HOST C:\Users\Administrator>exit
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to MY_WINDOWS_HOST closed.
Transferred: sent 3024, received 2792 bytes, in 166.9 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 18.1, received 16.7
debug1: Exit status 0
sysadmin@MY_LINUX_SERVER:~/ansible$
```

Attempt to connect with Ansible:

```
sysadmin@MY_LINUX_SERVER:~/ansible$ ansible -i staging iis -m win_ping -vvvv
<MY_WINDOWS_HOST> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator
<MY_WINDOWS_HOST> REMOTE_MODULE win_ping
<MY_WINDOWS_HOST> EXEC sshpass -d6 ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/sysadmin/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o Port=22 -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o User=Administrator -o ConnectTimeout=10 MY_WINDOWS_HOST /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445861196.89-92060959437896 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445861196.89-92060959437896 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1445861196.89-92060959437896'
MY_WINDOWS_HOST | FAILED => SSH Error: Failed to connect to new control master
    while connecting to A.B.C.D:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
sysadmin@MY_LINUX_SERVER:~/ansible$
```

Any clue why the connection is not working via Ansible?

Comment: What happens if you try `export ANSIBLE_SSH_ARGS='-o ControlMaster=no'` or setting `ControlMaster=no` in ansible.cfg?

Comment: Thanks, seems like I'm getting a different error now: [http://pastebin.com/hWJXnych](http://pastebin.com/hWJXnych)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the guys from Microsoft still didn't solve the file-descriptor passing issue so `ControlMaster` function is probably not working, even though it is not announced in advance. Disabling it as the comment proposes, should solve your issue. You can use also ansible config in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`:

```
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no
```

Comment: Thanks, followed previous comment and tried that. Seems like I'm getting a new error: [http://pastebin.com/hWJXnych](http://pastebin.com/hWJXnych)

Comment: Now you should check the server log (not sure where you can find it Windows), why was your password rejected. Are you sure the password is correct?

Comment: Yes, the password is correct. Checked the logs, it says:
`2092 06:59:36 719 Accepted password for Administrator from IP port 40174 ssh2
2092 06:59:36 719 fatal: ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to IP: incomplete message`

Comment: This message is not much verbose, but I think you can blame the command that is executed by `ssh`: `/bin/sh -c ` is probably not able to execute on Windows host. You can try from commandline if this simplified command will work you: `ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=no -o Port=22 -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o User=Administrator -o ConnectTimeout=10 MY_WINDOWS_HOST /bin/sh -c "echo hello"`

Comment: Makes sense. The command fails with the same error in the windows sshd log, and this is the execution log: [http://pastebin.com/Qm3pgNHe](http://pastebin.com/Qm3pgNHe)

Comment: You can try to modify the bash using `executable` option is config, but not sure what to put there instead.

Comment: I tried `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and they both seem to fail with the same error

Comment: This is probably material for bug report and some more intense debugging, if you can run shell without command and can't run command. From this output I can't read and help more.

Comment: Thanks. I did remove the -C parameter from the ssh command and it seems to connect (although still not running the command correctly). Not sure if its possible to configure Ansible to not use the -C parameter.

Comment: Oh. I though about this switch, but it felt unlike it can make difference. I don't see any switch to disable compression in ansible, but you can try to use `ssh_args -o Compression no`, but I am afraid that the `-C` switch takes precedence over the options like this.

Comment: Indeed I managed to get it to work, had to remove the -C parameter from the ssh command, and to call `cmd.exe /c "echo hi"`
[http://pastebin.com/4tRryt9e](http://pastebin.com/4tRryt9e)
So, I need both to remove the -C parameter from ansible ssh call, both change the executable and both change the `-c` passed to bash to `/c`

Comment: Great. One step closer. This will probably require some change in ansible code. And since it is open source, this can't be so hard :)

Comment: Thanks, apparently there's already a PR on Ansible for the compression flag, so I'll provide them with the info. [https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/10951](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/10951)